# Combine attributes with Powershell export

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell export from AD and now I want to merge a few of the field attributes (the last 3 fields) into one column in the CSV file.  Here is my code:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=All Users,DC=domain,DC=ca,DC=gov" -filter {(employeeType -eq "CEA" -OR employeeType -eq "Permanent Employee")} -Properties objectGUID, sAMAccountName, mail, employeeType, manager, department, division, extensionAttribute4 |
    Select-Object objectGUID, sAMAccountName, @{Label="mail";Expression={$_.mail.ToLower()}},  employeeType, manager, department, division, extensionAttribute4 | 
    export-csv -path "D:\System \UserAccounts.csv"
```

Can someone help?  thanks!

Comment: You evidently know how to, or have copied code that shows how to, create a property using `Select-Object`, why not just use that to do what you want?

Comment: I was finally able to -Join the Objects together into one cell.  Now they export into a csv file but merge all together.  Now I need to figure how to display them with a "/" between each of the Objects.

Comment: Excuse me that I am knew to asking questions in this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TheMadTechnician implies, you are already making a "calculated property" with `Select-Object` for your `mail` property. So then you just need to use this concept with building a string.

I took your code and combined the calculated `mail` property with `employeetype` and used the subexpression operator `$()` to evaluate the properties inside of the double quotes (string interpolation).

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=All Users,DC=domain,DC=ca,DC=gov" -filter {(employeeType -eq "CEA" -OR employeeType -eq "Permanent Employee")} -Properties objectGUID, sAMAccountName, mail, employeeType, manager, department, division, extensionAttribute4 |
     Select-Object objectGUID, sAMAccountName, @{Label="mail and employeeType";Expression={"$($_.mail.ToLower()) / $($_.employeeType)"}},  employeeType, manager, department, division, extensionAttribute4 |
     export-csv -path "D:\System \UserAccounts.csv"
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked how I wanted.  I'm sure my code is way longer than it needs to be, but it works for me.   I ended up having two Expressions.